# How to use the cursor proberty with position relative and why does it not work?

Tags: html, css, button, position, cursor

Hello guys I have been searching the net for quite some time now but I still can't fix it.

```
.login input[type="submit"] {
  background: #2196f3;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #0d47a1;
  color: #FFF;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 48px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 242px;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default a negative `z-index` puts the button behind the rest of the page, so the button isn't usable.

Try this:

```css
.login input[type="submit"] {
  background: #2196f3;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #0d47a1;
  color: #FFF;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 48px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 242px;
}
```

```html
<div class="login">
  <input type="submit" />
</div>
```

If you needed the z-index because you want it behind something else on the page, try increasing those elements' `z-index`. If you need it to be a disabled button, try adding `disabled="disabled"` in the HTML of the button.

Comment: Oh so the reason it did not work was the z-index and not the position? That explains why is I changed the position back it worked again, I mean z-index does not work on the default position. I will add the z-index to the other elements then, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because you give the `input[type="submit"]` a `z-index: -1;`

Maybe a `z-index: 0;` will work for you.